# Spacing between bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm fetching "boxes" and dynamically adding them into the HTML document with `ngFor`. I don't know in advance how many of them will be there. Currently i'm using this code:

```
<div *ngIf="items && items.length" class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items"
         class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">
        <app-single-item [item]="item"></app-single-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

What that gives to me:

[image]

Which is okay but the problem is I want bigger spacing between those elements. It should look like this:

[image]

To achieve the look on the second image I put `width: 21%` to `col-xl-3` and added `display: flex` and `justify-content: between` to the *row* div.

But the problem is, now if I have less than 4 boxes in a row, the spacing between them is much bigger. You can see it on the image below

[image]

My question is how can I get the same spacing between boxes regardless of the number. I don't want to use fixed width on the item `div`s that's why I use `col`s. and this is important, I need those items to always show from the beginning of the outer div, so in line with the element above it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `margin` right class of `bootstrap` for each column so that it appears to take some margin from right column like this

```
<div *ngIf="items && items.length" class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items"
     class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 mr-3">
     <app-single-item [item]="item"></app-single-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the problem with this approach is it pushes the last box in a new row

Comment: On the other hand, if I removed justify-content-between and kept 21% width with added margin, it does look better but I would like the boxes to span to the both outer div edges if 4 items are present.

Answer (score 0):

Keep width and use justify-content-center

Edit based on comment-

Apply container class to outer div and use -

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}
```

}

Comment: It doesn't start at the beginning of outer div then

Comment: I'm still not getting the desired result with this but there is a possibility I misunderstood you. Could you share your html just to be sure we kept the same classes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead updating the `margin` or `width` of your elements, you should update the **padding**, because it won't affect the outer but the **inner** element.

### Code example (not tested)

```
<div *ngIf="items && items.length" class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items"
     class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4 pr-2 pl-2">
     <app-single-item [item]="item"></app-single-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then with those principles, you can choose the space you want between elements.
And plus, maybe you don't want the first and last elements having `left` and `right`padding, so you may use [`media-queries breakpoints`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) to **remove** `pl-2` from first element and each `2n` elements for the `sm` breakpoint for example, and `pr-2` from second element and each `2n+1` elements for the `sm` breakpoint, (and an other math for other breakpoints, depending on how many elements are displayed by row).

[See the doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/)

Comment: I actually managed to get it work with margin. I left the size 21% for col div and put margin-right on every div except 4th child. That way i have a clean solution for xl resolutions.